# flutter upload doc, docx file to api laravel

Tags: flutter

What i have tired is i use file_picker to select select then i return as the code below.

Problem is when i printed out the cv: is empty. Or any another way to upload files to api?

//function flutter here

```
    String cvs;
  Future getFile() async{
    var tempFile = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.custom, allowedExtensions: ['doc', 'docx']);
    String fileString = jsonEncode(tempFile);

    setState(() {
      cvs = fileString;
      print(cvs);
    });
  }
```

// this is my data json code

```
var data = {
  'firstName': firstNameController.text,
  'lastName': lastNameController.text,
  'gender': genderController.text,
  'experience': experienceController.text,
  'field_id': _mySelection,
  'description_filed': descriptionFiledController.text,
  'cv_type': cvTypeController.text,
  'cv': cvs
};
```

//backend laravel code store information in database and google drive if file
`

```
public function storeApi(Request $req){



        $post = new Post;
        //To associate a user with a post,
        $field = Field::all();
        $cvs = new Cv;


        $validator = Validator::make($req->all(), [
             'firstName' => 'required|max:255',
             'lastName' => 'required|max:255',
             'gender' => 'required|max:255',
             'experience' => 'required|max:255',
             'cv' => 'required|max:100000|mimes:doc,docx',

        ]);
        if($validator->fails()){
      
        return redirect('/user/create_cv')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
    }
    else{
        $post->user()->associate(Auth::user());
        $post->firstName=$req->firstName;
        $post->lastName=$req->lastName;
        $post->gender=$req->gender;

        $post->field_id=$req->field_id;
       
        $post->experience=$req->experience;
        
        $post->description_filed=$req->description_filed;
        $post->cv_type=$req->cv_type;

        if($req->hasFile('cv')){


                $cvs->user()->associate(Auth::user());
                
                $cvs->cv = $req->file('cv')->store('google_folder_link', 'google');

                
                $cvs->url =  Storage::disk('google')->url($cvs->cv);
                $cvs->save();


        }


        $post->save();
    }
    return response()->json([
        'success' => "true",
        'message' => 'Post successfully',
        'post'    => $post,
        'cv'    => $cvs
        ]); 

    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the picked file as the following

```dart
File file = await FilePicker.getFile();
```

Once you get the file you can use `http` package to upload it using multipart request

```dart
_asyncFileUpload(File file) async {
    //create multipart request for POST or PATCH method
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse("<request_url>"));
    // add additional fields
    // request.fields["field1"] = value1;
    
    // create multipart using filepath, string or bytes
    var fileToUpload = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("file_field", file.path);
    //add multipart to request
    request.files.add(fileToUpload);
    var response = await request.send();

    //Get the response from the server
    var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
    var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
    print(responseString);
}
```

You can easily read a multipart file in PHP once you get it.